# MongoDB Aggregate If there is a match, the point should always increase with the new amount

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

If there is a match, the point should always increase with the new amount.

Thank you

*Example*: users.point : 0.01 new point: 0.02 new point + users.point >>> users.point = 0.03

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

```
   "users" : [ 
        {
            "userID" : "1",
            "point" : NumberDecimal("0.01")
        }

    ]

    client.db(dbProject).collection("test").aggregate([
                        { $match: {'_id': data.id} },
                        { $unwind: '$users' },
                        { $match: { 'users.userID': { $in: [data.userID]} }, },
                        { $project: {
                           _id: 0,
                           point: {
                                 $cond: { if: { $gte: ["$users.point", 0] },
                                          then: "ok", else: "no"}
                                 }
                        }}])
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your current data into DB and the expected output?

Comment: You can use the `$add` aggregate operator to add the new value to the existing value.